# Jetpack Compose: Custom TextField design

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-textinputlayout, android-compose-textfield

In general, most components in Jetpack Compose seem to be very easy to customize.

However, the same cannot be said for the `TextField`. For example, say that I wanted to make something like this:

[image: Custom text input]

One would think that simply wrapping the `BaseTextField` would work. However, it appears that there has been a bug in the `BaseTextField` component, and I have [opened an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171716885). This bug will not permit the user to focus the text field after focusing-away from it once already, until the component is re-rendered.

Citing this, I attempted to customize the `OutlinedTextField` and `TextField` components, but am not able to customize them to look like the image above. Were it not for the fact that the cursor color uses the `activeColor` property, I could make it work.

What would be a proper work-around to create a usable text field that looks like the above?

Comment: How do you show Character Counter below TextField?

Comment: @Thracian Well, you’d need to wrap everything in a column so that the counter appears below the text field, and then use the text field’s state to get the ‘.length’

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought it's a native component for TextField. Still no char counter, assistive text, and error message yet i guess.

Comment: How do you remove underline from TextField, i couldn't also remove that either. I'm trying to create a rounded corner TextField with no underline for TopBar search with leading icon. BasicTextField has no icon property so i'm trying to do it with TextField but if it's not working i will do it manually with BasicTextField and Image.

Comment: You need to add a border that's thick enough to cover the existing line

Answer (score 36, accepted):

By this exemple you can learn a lot. With 1.0.0 you can do like this:

[image: Custom TextField printscreen here]

```
Column {
        var textState by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        val maxLength = 110
        val lightBlue = Color(0xffd8e6ff)
        val blue = Color(0xff76a9ff)
        Text(
            text = "Caption",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(bottom = 4.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
            color = blue
        )
        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            value = textState,
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = lightBlue,
                cursorColor = Color.Black,
                disabledLabelColor = lightBlue,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
            onValueChange = {
                if (it.length <= maxLength) textState = it
            },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
            singleLine = true,
            trailingIcon = {
                if (textState.isNotEmpty()) {
                    IconButton(onClick = { textState = "" }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Close,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        Text(
            text = "${textState.length} / $maxLength",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 4.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            color = blue
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 47):

You can use the `TextField`:

- removing the label with `label = null`
- applying custom color with the `TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors` parameter to hide the indicator.
- adding in the `onValueChange` a function to fix the max number of characters as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67136278/2016562)

Finally use a `Column` to add 2 `Text` composables to complete the external label and counter text.

Something like:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val maxChar = 5

Column(){
    //External label
    Text(
        text = "Label",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
        color = Blue
    )

    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.length <= maxChar) text = it
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(vertical = 4.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        trailingIcon = {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "", tint = Blue)
        },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            backgroundColor = ....,
            focusedIndicatorColor =  Color.Transparent, //hide the indicator
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = .....)
    )
    //counter message
    Text(
        text = "${text.length} / $maxChar",
        textAlign = TextAlign.End,
        color = Blue,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption, //use the caption text style
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
```

[image]

Comment: backgroundColor is replaced by containerColor. i.e
containerColor = ...
not 
backgroundColor = ...
Anyway, thanks for solution

Answer (score 6):

Well, until the [issue I mentioned](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171716885) is resolved, the choices are:

1. Roll back to Compose version `1.0.0-alpha04` (issue was introduced in `alpha05`)
2. Add a border to a `TextField` or `OutlinedTextField` as so:

   ```
   TextField(
       value = myValue,
       onValueChange = myOnChange,
       modifier = Modifier.clip(myShape).border(5.dp, myColor)
   )
   ```

Comment: In newer versions, you have pass the shape to TextField itself, as it overwrites the clip parameter with the shape coming in there

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Gabriele Mariotti's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66580732/14004940) 
If you like to have custom color for your cursor, you can achieve it using:

```
Column(){
    //External label
    Text(
        ...
        ...
    )

    TextField(
        ...
        ...

        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            backgroundColor = ...,
            focusedIndicatorColor =  ..., 
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = ...,
            cursorColor = Color.Black)
    )
    //counter message
    Text(
        ...
        ...
    )
```